# Directory location of new page

Tags: pages, directory

I see from the WordPress dashboard, I can create many new pages. When I create a new page, can you please tell me where this new page will be created. I mean the `directory location` where this file will be created?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

WordPress does not create a new file in the filesystem when you create a page from the backend. The data you enter into the backend is saved to the MySQL database where it is retrieved by various and sundry queries and displayed by code in [one or more templates](http://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Hierarchy). There is no "directory location" for your individual pages, but the template files that control the page display can be found in `wp-content/themes/your-theme-name/`